# How can I send a command to USB mass storage under UWP development?

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, usb

How can I send a command to USB mass storage under UWP development?

I tried `Windows.Devices.Usb` and `Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice`, but they can't work on mass storage. Can a Windows Store app send a command to mass storage or not? Are there any documents talking about this?

2017.10.12 edit
base on
[Talking to USB devices, start to finish (Windows Store app)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn312121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

You can write a Windows Store app, if device class, subclass, and protocol code of the device is one of the following:
name:cdcControl, classId:02 * *
name:physical, classId:05 * *
name:personalHealthcare, classId:0f 00 00
name:activeSync, classId:ef 01 01
name:palmSync, classId:ef 01 02
name:deviceFirmwareUpdate, classId:fe 01 01
name:irda, classId:fe 02 00
name:measurement, classId:fe 03 *
name:vendorSpecific, classId:ff * *

USB mass storage classID is 08h
Does it mean I can't send SCSI vendor command to mass storage by UWP app?

Comment: Lookup the API call(s) you want to use on MSDN it will tell you which platform(s) they can be used on.

Comment: What kind of command are you talking about?

Comment: UrbanEsc : SCSI command, Under desktop development , I used createfile to get handle and deviceIOcontrol send command to device.